Particle system Help
Why is my particle system not spreading hair all over the plane?


hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Hair is covering the whole plane, but the Turbulence force field is pushing some of it so hard that it bends all the way around to the other side. This is possible (unlike real life) because, by default, hair does not collide with its own source. I don’t think adding such collision would be very helpful to you here, so I recommend you turn down the power of the Turbulence field so it doesn’t blow the hair so hard. How much, I don’t know. You’ll have to experiment with different power settings, recalculating the simulation each time (usually done by just replaying it from the beginning) to see the results.
